# Help understanding the construction of twisted cylinder

Tags: geometry, reference-request, manifolds

So, I am reading the geometry of 2-dimensional objects like cylinder, torus etc. from **John Stillwell's "Geometry of surfaces"** text.

While I understood the construction explained in the book- of a cylinder by defining it as a quotient $ \mathbb{R/{\Gamma}}$, I am having trouble in understanding the part about twisted cylinder mainly because I think my mind can't imagine how a twisted cylinder looks like and how it can be made from a mobius band (say M) simply by prolonging the transverse line segments of M, just as we made a cylinder out of a rectangular strip.

I think I will be able to understand the rest better if only I could picture it somehow. and  in my opinion, one line on it written in the book doesn't do a very good job at it. And other than this book there is just very little literature on it. Also, I am self studying so I don't have someone else to explain it to me.

It would be great if someone here could refer me to some source online that describes this construction better the the book does, or maybe they can explain it to me here.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Also feel free to add appropriate tags.

**Edit:** Directly quoted from the book-

*"The twisted cylinder C* is constructed by joining opposite sides of a parallel-sided strip S, but with a twist. The resulting surface cannot lie in ordinary three-dimensional space without intersecting itself, though a fairly representative part of it can. This part is the Mobius band M, obtained by joining opposite sides of a rectangle R with a (half) twist."*

Then it states what I wrote earlier. And after this, it goes on to explain how a twited cylinder can be easily described as a quotient surface. And that is where I got stuck. While I got how a cylinder can be described as a quotient surface mainly because I could imagine what the book was saying about how a cylinder can be made by simply folding a strip, but I'm lost in case of twisted cylinder. I have problem in both imagining it and how we can write it as a quotient surface.

Comment: I don't know the book you're reading and don't have access; could you perhaps summarize the details of the construction of a "twisted cylinder"? (The name suggests a flat manifold homeomorphic to a cylinder that is not metrically a product of a circle and a line, but that doesn't gibe with your description involving a Moebius band...?)

Comment: See the edit please. Also, a simple google search in the name of the book + author would lead you to pdf/ djvu link of this book. Not telling you to download it, but you can read the paragraph concerning this topic from there, if you wish. It's in Chapter-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Fix a positive real number $\ell$, and let $S = [0, \ell] \times \Reals$. The twisted cylinder may be interpreted as $S$ modulo the equivalence
$$
(0, y) \sim (\ell, -y).
$$
Alternatively, consider the infinite cyclic group of [*glide reflections*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_reflection),
$$
f_{n}(x, y) = (x + n\ell, (-1)^{n} y),\quad\text{$n$ an integer.}
$$
This group acts isometrically and properly discontinuously on the Euclidean plane, the vertical strip $S$ is a fundamental domain, and the twisted cylinder is the quotient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped clear up things! +1